# use `tf.to_float()` or `tf.image.convert_image_dtype()` in image pipeline for CNN?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-slim

I am modifying the `tf.slim` example using this file as a template [vgg_preprocessing.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/preprocessing/vgg_preprocessing.py) .

When I read the data from the TFRecord file using a clip from the `tf.slim` notebook ([slim_walkthrough.ipynb](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/slim_walkthrough.ipynb)) I get an image with distorted colors. It happens when the pre-processing script uses `tf.to_float()` changes the image tensor from `tf.uint8` to `tf.float32`.

`image = tf.to_float(image)`
[image]

`image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, dtype=tf.float32)`
[image]

Do the differences matter after you run it through a CNN? If so, which one is more appropriate for the `Vgg16` image processing pipeline? Does it matter if I switch to a different pre-trained model like `Inception`?

Here is the full method:

```
# tf.to_float() and tf.image.convert_image_dtype() give different results
def preprocess_for_train(image,
                     output_height,
                     output_width):
  # randomly crop to 224x244
  image = _random_crop([image], output_height, output_width)[0]
  image.set_shape([output_height, output_width, 3])

  image = tf.to_float(image)
  # image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, dtype=tf.float32)

  image = tf.image.random_flip_left_right(image)
  return image
```

Answer (score 3):

First, see the code blow:

```py
img_tensor = tf.image.decode_jpeg(img_raw)
print(img_tensor.shape)
print(img_tensor.dtype)
print(img_tensor.numpy().max())
   
a = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(img_tensor, dtype=tf.float32)
print(a.numpy().max())
print(a.shape)
print(a.dtype)

b = tf.to_float(img_tensor)
print(b.numpy().max())
print(b.shape)
print(b.dtype)

c = tf.cast(img_tensor,dtype=tf.float32)
print(c.numpy().max())
print(c.shape)
print(c.dtype)
```

the result is :

```
(28, 28, 3)
<dtype: 'uint8'>
149

## for tf.image.convert_image_dtype
0.58431375
(28, 28, 3)
<dtype: 'float32'>

## for tf.to_float
WARNING:tensorflow:From <ipython-input-6-c51a71006d6e>:13: to_float (from 
tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future 
version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.cast instead.
149.0
(28, 28, 3)
<dtype: 'float32'>

## for tf.cast 
149.0
(28, 28, 3)
<dtype: 'float32'>
```

From the above code and result , you can get

1. tf.to_float is deprecated, so it advice to use tf.cast ;
2. the tf.to_float add multiply  1/255.0 equals the tf.image.convert_image_dtype operation;

So , in my opinion , there's no big differences .

By the way , the TF version is：1.13.1.

Answer (score 1):

I realized my problem was entirely different.

The answer to the question above is:

- `tf.to_float([1,2,3])` produces just `[1.,2.,3.]`
- `tf.image.convert_image_dtype([image tensor with dtype=tf.uint8], dtype=tf.float32)` produces an image tensor that has been normalized to values between [0..1]

But my error was because `matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(image)` doesn't work with negative values of `dtype=tf.float32` caused by `mean_image_subtraction` for `Vgg16`. I discovered that casting values back to `uint8` seemed to fix all my problems with `imshow()`

`plt.imshow( np_image.astype(np.uint8) )`

Comment: `image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, dtype=tf.float32)`  Is it equivalent to multiplying the image with (1/255) ?

Comment: I mean if I use the tf.image.convert_image_dtype then I don't have to multiply the image with 1/255 anymore ?